# Fragments Overlapping

Tags: overlapping

In my application showing settings screen using Fragments, I have some inner Fragments 
for some options. When selecting an inner Fragment from a view in my application,displaying that inner fragment, but when i select some other fragments in my settings screen 
and select back fragments are overlapping.

How to handle these **fragment overlapping**.

Thanks in Advance,